# New gas stove + new flex gas line (Gas line wont fit the wall pipe)

Tags: gas, oven, natural-gas, stove, range

I went to Lowes and bought a new gas range, along with a new gas line that connects to it.

Lowes contractors came to install it, but the installer told me the sales rep sold me the wrong gas line, or that I need to replace the gas pipe leading to the gas range because it wouldn't fit the new line. He couldn't make it fit so I'm now stuck with a new range/oven but can't use it.

I went back and returned the gas line, and then went to the appliance department, and lo and behold the same rep was working. He insisted he sold everything right and that the installer was absolutely wrong. I even showed him the pictures in this thread, and he said the installer was mistaken.

He then proceeded to sell me what looked like the same gas line and re-scheduled the install. Not sure any of this makes sense.

Can anyone tell me what to actually buy for this to be installed? Because after hours of research, the only thing I know is that I need a 1/2" gas line (I believe inner diameter) rated 85k or higher BTU.

In the photos you can see the old gas line (silver), versus the new one they sold me (yellow).

New gas line fits the back of the appliance, but not the pipe in the wall.

Images:

https://ibb.co/bLqtjZh

https://ibb.co/Syw0ccr

https://ibb.co/tL5NZBm

https://ibb.co/2nbPH0Q

The range I purchased:

https://www.geappliances.com/appliance/GE-30-Free-Standing-Gas-Convection-Range-with-No-Preheat-Air-Fry-JGB735SPSS

Answer (score 0):

This could be as simple as the new line has a male nipple ( Blue line) installed on the end and it needs to be removed.

Then remove the old line, ( at the fitting marked in black) and you can install the new line with a female end on the valve with the male end.

If you do this yourself use a [Thread sealer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0012YO0Z4), and check all connections with some soapy water after the gas is turned on.

It's unbelievable that an installer could not figure this out.

[image]

Comment: Hey there, I think the issue is that the new line is too large to fit there. I suppose I should just take it off and try to screw the new one on, but it absolutely looks larger.

Comment: The yellow line fitting seems to be bigger diameter than the old line's female fitting.

Comment: There's hex flats on the old fitting right under the blue line area. Maybe undoing that will reveal female threading in the wall-attached fitting that the yellow line's male adapter will fit into?

Comment: Is the new yellow gas line labeled 1/2 inch or 3/4"?

Comment: If you blow up the pic you can see 1/2 stamped on the collar of the new line.

Comment: Remove the old male fitting at the blue line. Remove the fitting in the end of the yellow line from the new yellow hose. See if this threads into the female fitting on the wall. If it does not you need an adaptor or a smaller yellow line. If the fitting does thread in to the female fitting then remove the male fitting and put pipe dope or yellow PTFE tape sealer on the fitting and screw it in firm but not overtight. Now attach the yellow line to the male cone fitting no pipe dope needed.because the threads on that nut are only to compress the fitting.

Comment: Looks to me like a 1./2"IP X 3/8" Flare ball valve. The new yellow appliance connector is not going to work unless you use a 3/8 female flare to 1/2 male flare adapter.

Comment: Thank you all. We will get the adapter per your recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a male-female reducer, female to fit the new pipe, male (smaller)  then fits the appliance. It's usual with fuel pipes that the threads are l.h., and are marked as such, but I can't see any such on these. Maybe not applicable in your country. Again, location would be useful. In a lot of countries, messing with gas appliances is forbidden, but I'm surprised your 'fitter' didn't carry such an adaptor in his spares.